# How to highlight current page in menu item properly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, menu, menuitem

I have a menu which has generated dynamically from a database.
Now I want to highlight the current page in menu item but when I do that all my current menu items disappear suddenly. Don't understand why?

Noticed when using `$this->uri->segment(1)` caused my menu dissappear

Does anyone know how to make it works?

In my View file:

```
<div id="menu">
         <ul>
            <?php foreach ($tabMenu as $item) : ?>
                <?php echo buildListItem($item); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

In my helper:

```
function buildListItem($item) {
    $urlItemName = url_title($item->name, 'dash', TRUE); 
    $urlCatID = ($item->cat_id);
    $url = base_url() . $urlItemName. "/". $urlCatID;

    // item name is blog, add target into it 
    if ($urlItemName == 'blog') {
        $blog = "http://www.tumblr.com";
        return "<li><a href='" . $blog . "' target='_blank'>" . strtoupper($item->name) . "</a></li>";
    } else {
        return "<li class='". isSelected($item).  "'><a href='" . $url . "'>" . strtoupper($item->name) . "</a></li>";
    }
}

function isSelected($item) {
    $urlItemName = url_title($item->name, 'dash', TRUE);

    if ($this->uri->segment(1) === $urlItemName) {
        return 'menu_active';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of the active `<li>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `isSelected()` method.  You are returning `class='menu_active'` when you should only be returning `menu_active`.

In your `buildListItem()` method you are returning an `<li>` tag with the `class` attribute.  Then in your `isSelected()` method you are returning the `class` attribute again.  So I imagine the `<li>` ends up looking like this:

```
<li class='class='menu_active''><a href='{url}'>{name}</a></li>
```

Notice the `class` inside of the `class`.

Comment: I just removed the extra 'class', but it's still NOT working :( What's wrong?